# selecting every newest row for specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a table like so:

```
SN  | User | is_borrowed | date
105 |  1   |      1      |2019-1-1
105 |  1   |      0      |2019-2-1
105 |  1   |      1      |2019-3-1
106 |  2   |      1      |2019-4-1
107 |  1   |      1      |2019-5-1
106 |  2   |      0      |2019-6-1
106 |  2   |      1      |2019-8-1
107 |  1   |      0      |2019-9-1
107 |  2   |      1      |2019-10-1
```

Wanted output is to show what is borrowed (not returned) and user=1:

```
SN  | User | is_borrowed | date
105 |  1   |      1      |2019-3-1
```

Output for User=2 and borrowed (not returned):

```
SN  | User | is_borrowed | date
106 |  2   |      1      |2019-8-1
107 |  2   |      1      |2019-10-1
```

In summary I want a list of devices currently borrowed that are not returned for each user. Sadly nothing comes to my mind tho :/

Comment: "Wanted output is to show what is borrowed (not returned) and user=1:" "In summary I want a list of devices currently borrowed that are not returned for each user." User 105 has two borrowes which are not returned right?  `105 |  1   |      1      |2019-3-1` and `105 |  1   |      1      |2019-7-1`  or do i not understand the question right?

Comment: @RaymondNijland SN is serial number of device borrowed. User is User's id number

Comment: Yes i understand that let me reask the same question in the other way.. Why/How is it possible the user with 1 was capable into borrowing SN with 105 twice in a row without returning it first?

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry, my bad. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

looking to your expected  result  seems you are looking for the max(date) for  SN, user  where is_borrowed = 1

```
select SN, user, is_borrowed,  max(date)
from my_table 
where is_borrowed = 1 
group by  SN, user, is_borrowed
```

or for the device actual borrowed

```
Select * from my_table m
inner join t (
  select SN, is_borrowed,  max(date) max_date 
  from my_table 
  where is_borrowed = 1 
  group by  SN,  is_borrowed
) t on t.SN =  m.SN AND t.max_date = m.date
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't work in scenario when user return the device back and someone else borrows it. It still shows as if this first user borrowed it (the other one as well).

Comment: I don't see this scenario in you data sample  .. anyway i have added  suggestion that should cover this situation too

Comment: the latter code only shows that device with sn 107 is borrowed by the user 2.

Comment: @adammo  ..check better  ..  should retunrn 107,106 and 105

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.sn, t.user, t.is_borrowed, t.date
FROM TABLE_NAME t
WHERE t.is_borrowed = 1
AND t.date =
              ( 
                  SELECT MAX(x.date)
                  FROM TABLE_NAME x
                  WHERE x.user = t.user
              )
AND (
     SELECT xx.is_borrowed
     FROM TABLE_NAME xx
     WHERE t.sn = xx.sn
     AND t.date < xx.date
     ) <> 0
;
```

Comment: `t.is_borrowed = '1'` and `<> '0'` General MySQL rule if the datatype is a INT use a INT not a string with quotes.. MySQL's auto cast can mess things up and might be even unable to use indexing because that auto cast.